Typescript with Expo 'router.push'
I'm using some paths in Expo with typescript like this:
const [HomePath , SettingsPath, ProfilePath]  = [
  "/",
  "/settings",
  "/profile",
];

router.push(HomePath);


However, I got this error:
"Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Href<string | object>'",  
I tried
const HomePath : Href<string | object> = '/';

It fixed the type error, but it's a little complex, is there any better way?  Thanks!

You can cast all your paths as a Href<string> to satisfy typescript
const [HomePath , SettingsPath, ProfilePath]  = [
  "/",
  "/settings",
  "/profile",
] as Href<string>[];


I used to have my routes defined in a constant file as well. It seems the expo router now type checks all possible routes for us.
Just use router.push("/")
If the route does not exist, it will throw an error

Trivial, but I had the same issue and fixed it by restarting my expo app. I was editing the paths while running the app.
